# Angular JS: How to pass a list as a param in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I have a list of integers at the client side controller as :**

```
selectedSegments = [19,26]
```

Now, **I need to pass this list from client side to the back end** hence I am calling the back end service as :

```
return $http.post( 'dde/segments/deleteSegmentsForSelectedClient' ,{segmentIds: segmentIds } )
         .then
         (
             function( response )
             {
                 return response.data;
             },
             function( errResponse )
             {
                 console.error( ' Error while getting results of query'  + errResponse);
                 return $q.reject( errResponse );
             }
         );
```

**And service (java class)  side I have :**

```
@RequestMapping( "/dde" )
@RestController
public class SegmentController
{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( "apiSegmentService" )
    private SegmentService segmentService;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass() );



    @RequestMapping( value = "/segments/deleteSegmentsForSelectedClient", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "apiTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteSegmentsForSelectedClient( @PathVariable( "segmentIds" ) List<Integer> segmentIds )
    {

        for(int id: segmentIds)
        {
            try
            {
                segmentService.deleteSegmentEntity( id );
            }
            catch ( ParserException e )
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT );
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK );
    }

}
```

This class is working fine with other functions and with other type of params but **when I am trying to pass a list as param I am getting 500 error with the error message**:

```
Missing URI template variable 'segmentIds' for method parameter of type List
```

MAy I get help on how to pass param as list? Please let me know should I provide more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it as Query params ( as it is part of the `Path Variable` ) and not as part of request body ( `which is the case in your code`)

```
let source = 'dde/segments/deleteSegmentsForSelectedClient';
// construct the segmentIds key value
let params = 'segmentIds=' + segmentIds.join(',');

// append the params to the url
let url = [source, params].join('?');

$http.post( url)
         .then (
```

And at the controller level, you will need to modify

```
@PathVariable( "segmentIds" ) List<Integer> segmentIds
```

to

```
@PathVariable( "segmentIds" ) String segmentIds
```

And then extract the list from the string that is passed in.

Answer (score 1):

when dealing with java backend, avoid as much as possible to use lists as top level transfer objects.

usually jersey or any other runtime will have trouble figuring out a suitable list implementation to use.

try approaches [like](https://github.com/sombriks/sajadv/blob/master/sajadv-web/src/services/SajAdvClient.js) [this](https://github.com/sombriks/sajadv/blob/master/sajadv-core/src/main/java/br/com/softplan/sajadv/resource/SajAdvResource.java) [one](https://github.com/sombriks/sajadv/blob/master/sajadv-core/src/main/java/br/com/softplan/sajadv/resource/Page.java) [instead](https://github.com/sombriks/sajadv/blob/master/sajadv-web/src/features/processo/cadastro.js#L13).